# Grails resultTransformer not applicable for DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, hibernate-criteria

In my Grails code I want to use both pagination and distinctlist, however Grails doesn't support that.

So I Google some and found out put the line:

```
resultTransformer CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY
```

should fix this problem.

But for my environment it seems doesn't work well and throw an exception like following:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: resultTransformer() is applicable for argument types: (org.hibernate.transform.DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer) values: [org.hibernate.transform.DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer@49ddf47e]
```

Anyone got some ideas? It should work because I tried it work out at home.

Comment: Try using `setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)`?

Comment: Tried, but still the same issue.